# Formatting a serial number to include spaces

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a load of serial numbers in a database, but people have keyed them with spaces in random places, or without spaces.

The correct syntax is "123456 123456 1234 1234".

How can I format them all like that?

I've done this to remove all the spaces:

```
    REPLACE(Serial, ' ', '')
```

But now I need to put them back in the correct places.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you meant by *I need to put them back in the correct places.* ?

Comment: You should store them without spaces because that's the real data. Adding spaces is just formatting and thus should be done while outputting your data.

Comment: (1) What are the correct places?  (2) Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Sorry; I meant formatting them when I export the data. I'm writing a query which outputs it as a CSV, and it'd be nice to format them like that, rather than later needing to format it in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly this would work:

- First get rid of all spaces somewhere in your string.
- Use `STUFF` to push the blanks on the right position

Try this

```
 DECLARE @wrong VARCHAR(100)='1234 56 12  3456 1 234 1234';
 SELECT STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE(@wrong,' ',''),17,0,' '),13,0,' '),7,0,' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me in MS SQL, if you removed the spaces already:

```
declare @serial varchar(255) = '12345612345612341234';

set @serial = substring(@serial, 1, 6) + ' ' + substring(@serial, 7, 6) + ' ' + substring(@serial, 13, 4) + ' ' + substring(@serial, 17, 4)
print (@serial)
```

The result is what you expexted:

123456 123456 1234 1234